# Add value into JSON with PERL

Tags: json, perl, parsing

I create my json with PERL:

```
$perl_data{form . $num}{filed1} = {name_field => $name, type => $type, length => $max};
```

The result is this:

```
{
   "form1" : {
      "codifica" : "multipart/form-data",
      "filed0" : {
         "name_field" : "nome",
         "type" : "TEXT",
         "length" : ""
      },
      "action" : "nulla.php",
      "filed1" : {
         "name_field" : "cognome",
         "valore" : "mamma",
         "type" : "TEXT",
         "length" : "100"
      },
      "metodo" : "GET"
   }
}
```

If I want to add further data to JSON at `$perl_data{form . $num}{filed1}`  at a later date, how can I do that?

For example:

```
$perl_data{form . $num}{filed1} = {name_field => $name, type => $type, length => $max};
..code..
..code..
..code..
??? how i can add "key => $value" into $perl_data{form . $num}{filed1}?
```

Thank's!

Comment: Do you realise that your question has nothing to do with JSON? JSON is just a way of serialising complex data so that can be stored or sent to another program. The only action you should be performing on a JSON string is parsing it to recreate the data structure.

Answer (score 4):

```
$perl_data{"form$num"}{filed1}{key} = $value;
```